# Loss of quality when cropping smart objects in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, crop

I'm using a crop tool (or marquee tool, then Image -> Crop) in Photoshop CS4. Immediately after cropping, the quality of **anti-aliasing of Smart Object gets noticeably worse**.

[image: Before cropping]
[image: After cropping]

The blending mode of the smart object is Normal, and the opacity is 100%.
**I can flatten the image before cropping to preserve the quality**, but it's just an inconvenience each time.
**Is there a way to avoid this loss of quality of Smart Objects when cropping?**

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: Have you tried using a Layer Mask, instead of cropping?

Comment: I ended up using Ctrl+Shift+C to copy rendered pixels, then pasting them into a new document.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and does happen, I believe you can avoid it by making a smart object inside that smart object (with the same contents). Kind of annoying, but I believe that's how I handled it in the past.